# Why does the text field of DialogFlow's ResponseMessage contain a string array?

Tags: java, protocol-buffers, dialogflow-cx, protobuf-java

In the [example from Google's documentation](https://cloud.google.com/dialogflow/cx/docs/quick/api#detect-intent-drest), we see that the text responses from a `detectIntent` call are in the following format:

```
{
  "responseId": "38e8f23d-eed2-445e-a3e7-149b242dd669",
  "queryResult": {
    "text": "I want to buy a shirt",
    "languageCode": "en",
    "responseMessages": [
      {
        "text": {
          "text": [
            "Ok, let's start a new order."
          ]
        }
      },
      {
        "text": {
          "text": [
            "I'd like to collect a bit more information from you."
          ]
        }
      },
      {
        "text": {
          "text": [
            "What color would you like?"
          ]
        }
      },
      {}
    ],
    "currentPage": {
      "name": "projects/PROJECT_ID/locations/us-central1/agents/133b0350-f2d2-4928-b0b3-5b332259d0f7/flows/00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000/pages/ce0b88c4-9292-455c-9c59-ec153dad94cc",
      "displayName": "New Order"
    },
    "intent": {
      "name": "projects/PROJECT_ID/locations/us-central1/agents/133b0350-f2d2-4928-b0b3-5b332259d0f7/intents/0adebb70-a727-4687-b8bc-fbbc2ac0b665",
      "displayName": "order.new"
    },
    "intentDetectionConfidence": 1,
    "diagnosticInfo": { ... },
    "match": {
      "intent": {
        "name": "projects/PROJECT_ID/locations/us-central1/agents/133b0350-f2d2-4928-b0b3-5b332259d0f7/intents/0adebb70-a727-4687-b8bc-fbbc2ac0b665",
        "displayName": "order.new"
      },
      "resolvedInput": "I want to buy a shirt",
      "matchType": "INTENT",
      "confidence": 1
    }
  }
}
```

Specifically, the "text" field of the Text struct is an array.

This is consistent with the [definition of the Text type](https://cloud.google.com/dialogflow/cx/docs/reference/rest/v3/Text).  In the Java client, it is implemented as a `LazyStringArrayList`.

Why?

I haven't been able to create any scenario in DialogFlow where that string array is ever greater than size 1.  What is the purpose of the list?  And what is the use case for more than one element?  Does it break up large strings?  Should I just concatenate everything together?  Surely we should not be picking off element 0 of that list.

Is there a preferred way to getting that text array into something more digestible to the UI?